# Solve : $\frac{n}{2}(n+1)=2014+2k$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

$n,k$ are positive integers and $n>k$, solve the equation : $$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=2014+2k.$$

---

the first thing I did is to write the LHS as $(2n+1)^2$ but I face an equation like $ak+b=m^2$, I know it has infinitely many solution, I know how to deal with this kind of equation if the LHS in the latter one is a second degree polynomial (doing some factorization), but I can't do the same in this case, Can you show me to do it ?

Comment: how to solve if we dont know $k$?

Comment: I suppose, this is a part of a question?

Comment: @dato : you do solve it for $n,k$ (Diophantine equation).

Comment: @aziiri : Well it is a Diophantine equation, but due to the $n^2$ it's not a linear one and there is no general way to solve it.

Comment: @Dolma : this was proposed in a maths contest, and the absence of general way doesn't mean that we can't solve it (for instance if the LHS was $k^2$ instead of $2k$ it would be much easier).

Comment: @aziiri : sorry that's not what I was trying to say. What I said was that even if it is a Diophantine equation, there is no general way to solve those. But, indeed, that doesn't mean it can't be solved, just that the fact it is a Diophantine equation is of no much use ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $4028=n(n+1)-4k$

As we need $n>k, -k>-n$

$ n(n+1)-4k>n(n+1)-4n=n^2-3n$

$\implies n^2-3n<4028$

the roots of $n^2-3n-4028=0$ are $\frac{3\pm\sqrt{3^2-4\cdot1\cdot(4028)}}2=\frac{3\pm\sqrt{16221}}2$

$\implies 0<n<\approx 64.98$

As Inceptio has identified $n\ge 63, n=63, 64$

Answer (score 2):

$\dfrac{n(n+1)-4028}{2}=2k \implies n(n+1)-4028=4k \implies 4 |n$ or $n+1$.

$n>k$, for what values do you get positive values for this expression:$n(n+1)-4028$ ?

$n(n+1)-4028 >0 \implies n(n+1)>4028$ . When is this attainable? $\sqrt{4028} \approx63$

We can take $63(64)-4028=4k$ and $65(64)-4028=4k$

Now you have a constrain $n>k$. What happens when $n=67$? $k=132$ , it is not allowed. Therefore, you can conclude only two pairs of solutions: $(n,k)=(63,1)$ and $(64,33)$.

Comment: Yes I know that, what should do next ? casework yielded nothing.

Comment: Edited with a detailed answer.Have a look.

Comment: Yes, you're very right! As long as $n>k$, you can only have those two pairs of solutions, and this is because the function $k\mapsto n(k)-k$ is strictly decreasing so whenever it gets negative (i.e. when you find a $k_0$ such that $n\leq k_0$) then it will never get positive again and so $\forall k\geq k_0 , n\leq k$

Comment: Right . Also you can just argue with simple number theory. Which is closed under $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{N}$. SO, it cuts off many possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can rewrite the equation as:

$n^2+n-4(1007+k)=0$

You solve this equation the usual way and you get your condition on $k$:

$\Delta=1+16(1007+k)$

Now, $(\Delta=0)\Leftrightarrow(k=-(1007+\frac{1}{16})=k_0)$ and ($\Delta>0)\Leftrightarrow(k>k_0)$

In the first case, your resulting $n$ would be: $n=-\frac{1}{2}$ which is not in $\mathbb{N}$ so not a solution.

In the second case you have two possible solutions:

$\cases{n_1=\frac{-1-\sqrt{\Delta}}{2}=\frac{-1-\sqrt{1+16(1007+k)}}{2} \\ n_2=\frac{-1+\sqrt{\Delta}}{2}=\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+16(1007+k)}}{2}}$

For those to be in $\mathbb{N}$, the numerator needs to be a multiple of $2$ (and an integer of course).
Now you just have to find all the $k>k_0$ for which $n_1$ and/or $n_2$ is in $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: And you can also use the condition that Inceptio suggests:
$4|n$ or $4|(n+1)$ ;)

Comment: I can't see how this can be useful, $\Delta$ must be a perfect square which I can't find the specific values of $k$ that verify this (I said it in the bottom of the question).
@Inceptio : there are two solutions.

Comment: @aziiri : Inceptio was not asking how many solutions there was for each $k$ but how many there was in total (for all applicable $k$)

Answer (score 0):

If your equation is multiplied by $8$ and $1$ added to both sides you get 
$$(2n+1)^2=16k+16113.$$
An odd square is $1$ mod 8, and so is $16113$, so things look good. Then as noted by Inceptio only half of these actually work, giving $n=0,3$ mod $8$. So we can *start* with any such $n$ and just compute
$$k=\frac{(2n+1)^2-16113}{16}.$$
(If you use an $n=1,2$ mod 4 what happens is this formula gives a half integer for $k$.)